# Generate in and out xsd(schema) for each operation from the wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl, soapui

Generate in and out XSD(schema) for each operation from the WSDL using java.

I have a WSDL file and want to generate the separate in and out XSD(schema) for every operation. I have used the soupUI jar for the same.

Below is my WSDL and the code to generate the XSD(schema) for every operation.
Please find the WSDL at http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl

Here is the code I have used:

```
public class SOAPInputGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final String INPUT_PARAMETERS = ">?<";

        WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
        WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl");
        WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0];
        for (Operation operation : wsdl.getOperationList()) {
            WsdlOperation wsdlOperation = (WsdlOperation) operation;
            String operationName = wsdlOperation.getName();
            System.out.println(wsdlOperation.createRequest(true));
            String requestString = wsdlOperation.createRequest(true);
            Document doc = getDocumentFromSoapRequestString(requestString);
            Element docElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
            System.out.println(docElement.getTagName());
            NamedNodeMap allAttributes = docElement.getAttributes();
            NodeList headerElements = 
                    docElement.getElementsByTagName("soap:Header").item(0) != null ? docElement.getElementsByTagName("soap:Header") : docElement.getElementsByTagName("soapenv:Header");
                    System.out.println("SOAP header :"+headerElements.item(0).getNodeName());
                    docElement.removeChild(headerElements.item(0));
                    if (docElement != null && allAttributes != null) {
                        while(allAttributes.getLength() != 0)
                        {
                            Node attr = allAttributes.item(0);
                            System.out.println("*************Node : ******"+attr.getNodeName());
                            docElement.removeAttribute(attr.getNodeName());
                        }
                    }
                    String simpleXmlStr = returnDocumentInString(doc);
                    simpleXmlStr = simpleXmlStr.replaceAll("soapenv", "Operation").replaceAll("soap", "Operation").replaceAll(":", "");
                    System.out.println(simpleXmlStr);
                    if (simpleXmlStr.contains(INPUT_PARAMETERS)) {
                        generateXsd(operationName, simpleXmlStr);
                    }
        }
    }

    public static String returnDocumentInString(Document doc) {
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer;
        try {
            transformer = tf.newTransformer();
            transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException transformerConfigurationException) {
            System.out.println(transformerConfigurationException.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        catch (TransformerException transformerException) {
            System.out.println(transformerException.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return writer.toString();
    }

    public static Document getDocumentFromSoapRequestString(String xmlString) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString))); 
        return doc;
    }

    private static void generateXsd(String operationName, String soapRequestXml) throws IOException, ParseException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, TransformerException {
        FileWriter  fw = new FileWriter("exmp.xml");
        fw.write(soapRequestXml);
        fw.close();
        XsdGen gen = new XsdGen();
        File tempFile = new File("exmp.xml");
        gen.parse(tempFile);
        File out = new File(operationName+".xsd");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        gen.write(new FileOutputStream(out));
        Document doc = builder.parse(operationName+".xsd");
        Element docElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
        docElement.setAttribute("targetNamespace", "Default target name space for data mapper");
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(operationName+".xsd"));
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        tempFile.delete();
    }
}
```

I would like to know if is it good and safe approach to use the soupUI jar for the same?
Is there any alternative way to achieve the same?